# Tidy CSS for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, htmltidy, csstidy

Is there some kind of CSS tidy available for Notepad++. I have tried what seems to be every menu item in TEXTFX but none seem to do it. I am used to using PSPAD where you just select the CSS and clicked "Reformat Into Structured CSS"

**EDIT** made a discovery a long time after asking this question which may help others ... there is a big difference between `tidy css` and `format css`. It was actually the latter I was looking for and there are several online systems, for instance http://procssor.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have scoured the net and as far as I'm concerned the answer to this question is NO, or at least if there is I certainly cant find it; but if anyone comes up with a better answer I will accept it. For me I will continue to use PsPad for this operation.

Answer (score 30):

I was looking for this functionality myself, so I wrote this pair of regex search-and-replace based macros for Notepad++. *Format CSS* formats a CSS document while *Minify CSS* makes it smaller.

To install them, locate your *shortcuts.xml* file, usually at

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml

and paste the whole block into the `<NotepadPlus><Macros>` block.

*You need to use another editor than Notepad++, OR close Notepad++ by killing the process after you edit this file. Otherwise, **Notepad++ will overwrite the file on close.***

After installing, you can run those macros from the Macros menu in Notepad++, as well as rename them or assign hotkeys using *Edit shortcut/delete macro*.

In case someone finds a css for which this script doesn't work, please make a [paste](http://pastebin.com/) and post the link in the comments so I can look at it.

#### Macro source XML

```
<Macro name="Format CSS" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="([^\r\n;])\}(?![\r\n])" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\1;\r\n}\r\n" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="([^\r\n])\}(?![\r\n])" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\1\r\n}\r\n" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="([^\r\n])\{(?![\r\n])" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\1\r\n{\r\n" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=";(?![\r\n])" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=";\r\n" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="(^(?![ \t]).+;)" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="    \1" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\}(?!(\r?\n\r?\n))" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="}\r\n" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=":(?![ ])(?=.+;)" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=": " />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
</Macro>
<Macro name="Minify CSS" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="[\r\n\t ]+" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="[ ]*\}[ ]*" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="}" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="[ ]*\{[ ]*" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="{" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="[ ]*;[ ]*" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=";" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=";\}" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="}" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="[ ]*:[ ]*" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=":" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  There are a few errors though and I don't know enough about how this works to fix it. Mostly has to do with spacing.  It also inserted an extra semicolon somehow.  I wish I StackOverflow had a better commenting system so I could show you.

Comment: @DerekZiemba you can make a [paste](http://pastebin.com/) and post the link here. How this works is: the `message="1601"` fields are the "find" regex, the `1602` fields are the "replace" expression. Each search and replace operation is one whole block `1700`–`1701`, and the blocks are executed top to bottom, each doing a global search and replace on the file.

Comment: Great! Using the macro it took 10 seconds to reformat 50K lines of css code.

Comment: Very fast, even Aptana Studio failed to format the source, this macro did, Thank you!

Comment: Here is a [test file](https://pastebin.com/BCBuQ44y) for some problems with @-rules, comments (missing linebreak after comment) and url(data) terms.

Comment: @Stony Thanks. Unfortunately, as soon as nesting scopes are introduced, things get extremely difficult to handle with regexes. Will probably not fix that.

Comment: Just here to say how great this macro is.

Answer (score 4):

What about JSFormat function of the JSTool plugin?
I know it is unexpected, the name refers to Javascript.
It has a format and a minification functionality that work on css too.

Comment: works, but you need to do some cleaning after. described here: [Notepad++ plugin for auto format Css - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525131/notepad-plugin-for-auto-format-css#comment87876723_28525173)

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of plugins for Notepad++ out here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central

Just do a search for CSS and try out those plugins. I don't use such a plugin, so no recommendation here.

Maybe CSS-eXplorer or jN?

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I don't think either of those or anything else on that page will work TBH