# Notepad++ plugin for auto format Css

Tags: css, plugins, autolayout, notepad++, auto-indent

I'm looking for a **plugin for Notepad++** that will auto align (auto format) my **Css** files. Something similar to visual studio ctrl+k, ctrl+d effect only for notepad++.

Anybody know something like that? [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tidy CSS for Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835894/tidy-css-for-notepad)

Comment: Best use: Chrome's inbuilt pretty print.

Comment: Workaround as long as there is no plugin: Use an online tool like https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/ or https://codebeautify.org/css-beautify-minify

Answer (score -6, accepted):

try JSON Viewer...
after installing select all content of css and  "Ctrl + shift + alt + m" . It will format your css.

Comment: I tried this but it formatted the css according to javascript rules not according to css rules.  It made the css less readable instead of more readable, imo.

Comment: There are some online tools to beauty css like http://www.codebeautifier.com/  and http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/

Comment: Downvoted, because obviously it wasn't tested. When I tried, as @JasonL.   said, it made the code less readable and not arranged it according to CSS rules.

Comment: I agree. This doesn't work. It formats JSON not css.

Comment: It does not work for css. I tried and failed.

Comment: i found it here: [JSONViewer Notepad++ plugin download | SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/?source=typ_redirect) but be careful, because you need to perform these replaces after it: `[ = | - | % | / | # ]` to `[=|-|%|/|#]` an still you have trouble with lines like this: `animation: spin .6s;` because will translate like this: `animation: spin.6s;`

Comment: Also, be careful because it strips the first period of the file when you start with a class selector, and it also strips the last }

Comment: it works only for json not for css

Comment: https://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2016/12/how-to-format-css-in-notepad.html worked for me

Comment: This just deletes all the text for me. :(

Comment: @elPolloLoco JSTool wrecks your CSS because it formats the file according to JavaScript rules (it's ok if you're just looking for something in a minified CSS file, but **DON'T SAVE** the formatted version! Close it without saving once you found what you're looking for.). I'm shocked that there's no dedicated plugin for CSS in Notepad++ how did it not happen yet?!

Comment: @ADTC thx, thats some good advice

Comment: @elPolloLoco thank you. Yes the most obvious anomaly is that it changes all the `-` to be `‍ - ‍` instead (with spaces around the dash), perhaps because it thinks it's the subtraction operator in JavaScript. If you find/replace it back to `-` you'll get some semblance of CSS, but you'll still find other anomalies.